# Whats is the reason to write that code(greasemonkey script) so crypted?

Tags: javascript

I found this: [click](https://monkeyguts.com/code.php?nav=code&id=273) and thought what are the reasons behind this coding style  ?

Defining identifiers like that `_0x3384x4`, kind of unreadable for a human ...?!

or writing object properties like:

```
{
    "\x63\x68\x61\x72\x73": ' \uD83D\uDE23 ',
    "\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73": '_1az _1a- _2gc',
    "\x6E\x61\x6D\x65": 'Bi\u1EC3u t\u01B0\u1EE3ng vui 18'
}
```

this could be written like that, couldn't it ?

```
{ chars="  ", class="_1az _1a- _2gc", name="Biểu tượng vui 18"}
```

Is it because of some old computers that can not display these characters? Is it kind of uglifying, protecting javascript code?

What kind of format is it (`0x7892x8`) kind of hex, what does it represent ? `(eval("0x7892")` evaluates `30866`, but `0x7892x8` means 8th version of `30866` ... doesn't make sense for me ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is no coding style. It is [`obfuscation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)).

From Wikipedia:

> In software development, obfuscation is the deliberate act of creating
>   obfuscated code, i.e. source or machine code that is difficult for
>   humans to understand. Like obfuscation in natural language, it may use
>   needlessly roundabout expressions to compose statements.
>
> Programmers may deliberately obfuscate code to conceal its purpose
>   (security through obscurity) or its logic, in order to prevent
>   tampering, deter reverse engineering, or as a puzzle or recreational
>   challenge for someone reading the source code.
>
> Programs known as obfuscators transform readable code into obfuscated
>   code using various techniques.

There are many Tools out there, called `Obfuscator`, which obfusecate Code. Here is a Javascript Obfuscator for example:

http://www.jsobfuscate.com/

As you already right guesed it is hexadecimal. So for example `x63` means `99 decimal`.

Now we take a look into the Code Table:

http://www.codetable.net/

And we see, `99 decimal` represents for example the `c` char.  So `\x63` basicly is `c`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is this(https://monkeyguts.com/code.php?nav=code&id=817) also obfuscated, because writing "u" or "e" as an identifier does not seem readable at all and I can not even pretty print that code ?!

Comment: @user3128022 `\x` is `Asci`, `\u` is `Unicode`, `\e` I don't know, never seen before.